# Durable Sagas in Mass Transit using NHibernate - What should happen after a service restart?

Tags: masstransit, saga

I have moved from the `InMemorySagaRepository` to use the `NHibernateSagaRepository` so that my sagas are durable when services restart.

I can see that my sagas are being persisted to the database and the state of the saga is being held in one of the table columns.

**What should happen if I stop a service while it is processing a saga and then restart it?**

My expectation is that the saga would restart from where it left off but this is not happening. **Is there something I need to do for my sagas to continue processing after a service restart?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Saga repository takes care of *state* persistence. Processing is something you do in transition from one state to another, and I don't believe there's anything in MT to help you resume your *transition*.

Once the state is restored, the saga will respond to the usual triggers delivered via messages.